# Some chance for social non-distancing in the UK?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Good participation about Sinclair questions (among others) made me belive, that there is a reasonable number of RC.SE members based in the UK. Since last week and for the next 6 weeks, I'm pushing a narrowboat from Staffordshire to London (having past B'ham, heading for Oxford, down the river Thames and back via the Grand Union).

Anyone interested to sit down for a pint or two and have a professional chat about electronic waste and how to handle it? I'd love to be drowned in mail at `ORG` on `VCFe.ORG`.

Comment: UK politicians aren't being particularly sensible about the safety measures, so it's best to _overshoot_ them if possible. (I understand the title's supposed to be witty, but when this appears on Hot Meta Posts some people will probably take this the wrong way.)

Comment: Well, for one, in pubs social distancing is not existent - and explicite not requested, by the UK government - they are more interested in saving Weatherspoon than any citizen. So the non-distancing is quite literal , as soon a we're on the same table.

Comment: The UK government's priorities are messed up. Stay safe, regardless of what they say is legal.

Comment: Yes. Indeed. :)